# Misconfigured files on an emulated SSH server and now ping, traceroute, and Docker are not working on my host VM. (SSH, apt and browser still work.)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, ping

**TLDR:** On a class-assigned virtual machine, ping traceroute and the original script used to access a Docker container/emulated VM stopped working after exiting a SSH session with the emulated VM. This program was run from a Docker container within my class assigned host VM. The host VM runs on Ubuntu.

I need to fix ping, traceroute, and my ability to access the original script and emulated VM in order to repair my school-assigned remote desktop and continue doing my classwork. Resetting the desktop environment entirely did not fix the problem. SSH connects, browser works, and traceroute runs but the results are 30 hops with three asterisks for each hop.

All of these issues showed up at once after exiting the SSH session with the emulated VM. There are a couple things I haven't narrowed down yet (ARP Tables and Socket Interface-- I will be back tomorrow to update.) Hopefully this will at least get the question to be more concise.

---

#### Context

I am working from a class-assigned virtual machine, and ran into issues while exiting a program used to emulate another virtual machine on that class assigned desktop environment. The following details are part of a homework assignment I was working on, and were all done in the emulated VM within that original class assigned VM.

*I cannot go back to assess the exact files and settings I changed in the target machine, as the script to set up the emulated SSH server/VM/Docker container on my host machine is not launching.*

Here is what I know I did on the emulated VM before returning to my host VM.

- I made a user with no home folder, root privileges, and a UID and GID under 1000.
- I configured the sudoers file to allow root access without a password.
- I changed the `sshd_config` file to allow ssh access to a port other than port 22.

  While formatting the `sshd_config` file on the target machine, I made a mistake that would override Port 22 with Port 2222.

This was done by adding an extra line under the current port listing so that `sshd_config` looked like this:

```
#Port 22
#Port 2222
```

Port 22 was commented out when I went to edit the file, and I was able to access the target machine through Port 22 with no issue, so I thought nothing of it at the time.

I have no answers as to why a commented port would still function, and I do not see any way that this would cause the current issues I am having with my host VM.

The ports on my host VM are open and functioning.

*This could potentially be negligible extra information, but I noticed the problems on my host machine immediately after making these changes and exiting the target machine. These problems were not present before I started interacting with the target machine. If there are problems that can arise simply from entering or exiting a SSH session with a Docker container improperly, that's a much more likely solution than connecting the session itself to current issues.*

#### Issues With Docker/Starting Emulated VM

In this case Docker is required to access the target machine because it is an emulation of a SSH server running from a script. Without this function, I am unable to access the target machine and troubleshoot how the changes I made in the target machine correlate with the issues on my host machine.

The emulated VM startup message indicates that Docker is running, but it is not launching the required script to access the target machine. Here is the error message:

> Apps aren't launching. Something is wrong.
>
> Try restarting the VM, then restart Docker.
>
> Then run the script again.

Restarting Docker does not change the status of this message, and neither does rebooting *or* resetting the machine. There may be something wrong with the script running the target machine, but examining it myself I can't see anything wrong, much less anything wrong that would mess with my host VM to the point that a full reset doesn't resolve the issue.

#### Issues With Ping and Traceroute

When I try to ping most IPs, it stalls out at the first line, and I have to exit the process manually, as I am not given a failure message.

Using `ping -c 3 -w 12 1.1.1.1` to limit the count and deadline of the ping request shows:

```
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% >packet loss, time 11249ms
```

I *am* able to ping localhost and 127.0.0.1, and pinging 0.0.0.0 works fine.
The internal firewall is disabled and ICMP is enabled.

When I use the example interface ping command, `ping -I interface google.com` I am given the output

```
ping: SO_BINDTODEVICE interface: No such device
```

*If you have any experience with socket programming your advice here would be invaluable, as I think this may be where things are going wrong.*

Traceroute runs but the only output is 30 hops all showing three asterisks each.

#### Attempted Solutions

The configuration files on my local machine do not reflect the configuration file changes I recorded making on the target machine, so any tampering with the target machine's settings shouldn't have affected the local machine, and I did not accidentally change configuration on my local machine thinking it was the target machine.

I *am* able to ping localhost and 127.0.0.1, and pinging 0.0.0.0 works fine.

The internal firewall is disabled and ICMP is enabled.

I did a full system reset of my local VM, and ping, traceroute, and Docker/the emulated VM are still malfunctioning. The fact that the configuration issue stuck even after a full system reset is very confusing to me, but may narrow down the cause. Is there a system setting or networking malfunction that would stay consistent through a full system reset?

I have alternatives to my virtual machine but I still would consider this a time sensitive issue, as I cannot use my backup VM for certain projects. I will edit the question and clarify with more solutions I have already tried as I go through potential options.

#### Potential Solutions Not Attempted Yet

Socket configuration.

ARP table configuration.

Further investigation on the emulated VM startup process and where exactly it's failing.

Further investigation on why the issues may have stayed the same despite a full system reset.

*I don't need a comprehensive answer, just pointers in the right direction! Will keep updating tomorrow. Still a lot of things to rule out.*

Comment: What's an "emulated VM"? A Docker container? What OS is the main VM running?

Comment: Why don’t you just request the VM be rebuilt?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yep, the emulated VM was running from a docker container, and the main VM runs Ubuntu-- will update the main post with those details now

Comment: @Ramhound Mainly because I want to know the mechanics of what went wrong in case I run into something like this again, I might bring it to the school’s attention if I run out of options but right now I’m considering this a learning experience

Comment: @pieris_rapae1999 Happy this was solved but _please do not edit your question_ to essentially say, “Solved!” Instead, please place the three paragraphs at the top in its own answer and be sure to check it off as an answer.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thanks for the final bit of advice! I added an answer but it says there's a 24 hour waiting period between answering and accepting the answer, I'll accept the answer as soon as I can so this whole debacle can be put to rest at last :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was configuration issue, it has been resolved and requires no further answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been resolved, and is up for personal posterity. The host VM was never configured to properly run ping, which I didn't consider because I was busy attempting different troubleshooting angles available for ping while assuming I had broken something fundamental within the configuration files.

I contacted the instructor of the class and he reset the host VM, which fixed the Docker container used to launch the emulated VM, and he clarified the issues with ping and traceroute as being part of the system itself.

I specifically may ask more questions about socket programming later however it ended up being irrelevant to the current situation.